# Input not processed through InputMultiplexer

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm attempting to process 2 different inputs - One from an InputProcesser, and another from a Scene2D stage. For some reason it works when I use

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

but not when I use

```
InputMuliplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(stage);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```

I can't seem to find an answer to why it does this. I tried returning false in the handler, but it had no effect. Here's the relevant main file:

```
public class PlanetClicker extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Planet planet;
    Skin skin;
    Stage stage;
    Picture era;
    Label countLabel;
    GlyphLayout glyphLayout;
    BitmapFont bitmapFont;
    Picture buildings;
    Picture food;
    Picture resources;
    Group resourceGroup;
    InputMultiplexer multiplexer;
    final float clickMultiplier = 0.95f;
    //Height and Width of window. Used to check for resize event.
    float previousWidth;
    float previousHeight;
    int buildingCount = 0;
    int foodCount = 0;
    int resourcesCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        stage = new Stage();

        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
        era = new Picture(new Texture("cavemen.png"),0,0);

        buildings = new Picture(new Texture("building.png"), 0, 0);
        food = new Picture(new Texture("food.png"), 0, 0);
        resources = new Picture(new Texture("resources.png"), 0, 0);
        buildings.setPosition(0,food.getHeight()+resources.getHeight());
        food.setPosition(0, resources.getHeight());
        resourceGroup = new Group();
        resourceGroup.addActor(buildings);
        resourceGroup.addActor(food);
        resourceGroup.addActor(resources);
        buildings.setBounds(buildings.getX(),buildings.getY(), buildings.getWidth(), buildings.getHeight());

        planet = Data.getCurrent();
        previousHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        previousWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        planet.setMultiplier(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / planet.getInitial_width() * 0.325f);
        countLabel = new Label("", skin);
        glyphLayout = new GlyphLayout();
        bitmapFont = new BitmapFont();

        stage.addActor(era);
        stage.addActor(planet);
        stage.addActor(countLabel);
        stage.addActor(resourceGroup);

        multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(stage);
        //multiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
        //multiplexer.addProcessor(this);

        buildings.setBounds(buildings.getX(), buildings.getY(), buildings.getWidth(), buildings.getHeight());
        buildings.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
        ClickListener listener = new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                System.out.println("Hiya");
                return false;
            }
        };
        buildings.addListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        countLabel.setText("Buildings: "+ buildingCount);
        glyphLayout.setText(bitmapFont, countLabel.getText());

        stage = new Stage();
        stage.addActor(era);
        stage.addActor(planet);
        stage.addActor(countLabel);
        stage.addActor(resourceGroup);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);

        if(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()!=previousHeight || Gdx.graphics.getWidth()!=previousWidth) {
            planet.setMultiplier(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / planet.getInitial_width() * 0.325f);
            previousWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
            previousHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        }

        batch.begin();
        planet.setX(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2- planet.getWidth()/2);
        planet.setY(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2- planet.getHeight()/2);

        era.setX(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-era.getWidth()/2);
        era.setY(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/9); //Arbitrary number, just seems to work

        countLabel.setX(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-glyphLayout.width/2);
        countLabel.setY(8*Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/9); //Also arbitrary

        resourceGroup.setX(0);
        resourceGroup.setY(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-buildings.getHeight()/2-food.getHeight()/2-resources.getHeight()/2);

        stage.draw();
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        planet.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
    }

    //---KEY-TESTS---

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        if(planet.pointInsidePlanet(screenX,screenY)) {
            planet.setMultiplier(clickMultiplier * planet.getMultiplier());
            planet.setClicked(true);
            buildingCount++;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        if(planet.isClicked()) {
            planet.setMultiplier(planet.getMultiplier() / clickMultiplier);
            planet.setClicked(false);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The 2 things I'm testing for is the TouchDown in ClickListener and later in the class. It doesn't work with the class added or left out of the multiplexer. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - The problem was that the Multiplexer had to be initialized in the render() method for some strange reason.

Comment: It's because you instantiated a second Stage in render(), leaking the first one. Also, since you're doing it in render, you are leaking ~60 stages per second and your game will crash before long.

Comment: Yeah, if I didn't put it there the stage doesn't update on resize. If you have a better solution, I'd be happy to hear it. If I dispose the stage before instantiating it, would that fix it?

Comment: Yes, but it would be ridiculous to be instantiating new ones every frame, especially to avoid fixing a bug. Not sure what you're doing wrong. I don't see your resize method. The right way to do this is instantiate everything in create(). The new keyword should not appear in your render loop.

Comment: That would probably be a lot easier. It's very tempting to put everything into the render loop. Thanks a lot - I'm still learning good practices.

Comment: Moved half the methods in render to resize - thanks: I'll create a massive performance boost in the future.